# How to efficiently develop spring-boot microservice that synchronise data in real-time with firestore of google firebase cloud?

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, synchronization, google-cloud-firestore

The work method Firebase suggests and recommends is to link the Front-End application directly with the FireStore database service, and this provides real-time synchronization between the data in the Front-End application and the documents in FireStore, which is managed by the AdminSDK Firebase.
However, I would like to implement a business layer (following a micro-services architecture) with Spring-boot, but in this case it is up to me to manage the synchronization in real time between my micro-services and the front-end application.
So, How to efficiently develop spring-boot microservice that synchronise data in real-time with firestore of Google Firebase Cloud ?
Which framework or protocole I would use to brige this fonctionality ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you could pass this by adding fabiomaffioletti (specific connector to firebase -- you could find it on github), you can refactor your entities by changing it to @FirebaseDocument("/people") to the entry point on firebase /people, 
This denpendency would give the same actions as a normal repository by creating an interface anotate by repository that can give spring boot the possibility to scan the
repositories

```
@Repository
public class PeopleRepository extends DefaultFirebaseRealtimeDatabaseRepository<People, long> {
}
```

Don't forget to add @EnableFirebaseRepositories on your main apllication class.

Finaly on your properties file add this properties to precise the firebase end-point:

```
firebase.service-account-filename=[classpath|file]:[service-account-filename].json
firebase.realtime-database-url=[realtime database url]
```

Hope this would help you.
My apologize for my bad english :D